# Table filter getting reset vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tablefilter

I have filters for each column in my table and the filter works fine when i type in for one column and when i filter another column in parallel, the results shows only for the second filter (means the first filter i typed is getting igonored). Always the latest filter works.

//computed

```
filteredList: function () {
         
            var vm = this.vm;
            var columnFilters = this.columnFilters;
            var list = [...this.vm.entries];
            var search, value;

            var filteredIndexes = Object.keys(this.columnFilters);
            if (filteredIndexes.length > 0) {
                filteredIndexes.forEach(function (index) {
                   
                    if (columnFilters[index] != '') {
                       
                        list = vm.entries.filter(function (row) {
                           
                            search = columnFilters[index].toLowerCase();
                             value = row.rowItems[index].itemDisplay.toLowerCase();
                            return value.includes(search);
                        });
                    }
                });
              
            } 
             return list;
        },
```

Where i'm going wrong?

Comment: I've not dabbled much in vue, but a quick Google shows that the filter function returns a list of values and I don't see any parallel computing here.  It looks like your setting your list variable equal to the output of the first filter than reassigning it to the output of the second

Comment: Yeah, is there anyway i can make the reassign work within this?

Comment: I would use the `map` function instead of `forEach`.  If u look into how that works it should sort u out.  Otherwise u might need some further study in general js syntax.